# How to create a KieContainer producer using the KieScanner?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, cdi, drools, kie

I need a CDI injectable KieContainer, which uses the KieScanner to update the rules when a new rules package is added to the maven repository. The method below is working fine, it is however leaking memory because a new TimerService is created by the KieScanner every time the KieContainer is injected. How can I create a KieContainer producer method using the KieScanner that does not start a new KieScanner for every KieContainer that is injected?

```
@Slf4j
@Singleton
public class KieContainerProducer {

    private static final String PROPERTIES_FILENAME = "scanner.properties";

    @Produces
    public static KieContainer produceContainer() {
        try {
            ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            try (InputStream is = loader.getResourceAsStream(PROPERTIES_FILENAME)) {
                properties.load(is);
            }
            KieServices ks = KieServices.get();
            ReleaseId releaseId = ks.newReleaseId(
                    properties.getProperty("groupId"),
                    properties.getProperty("artifactId"),
                    properties.getProperty("version"));
            KieContainer kContainer = ks.newKieContainer(releaseId);
            KieScanner kScanner = ks.newKieScanner(kContainer);
            kScanner.start(60000L);
            return kContainer;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            log.error("Properties file scanner.properties not found.");
            log.debug("FileNotFoundException: ", ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            log.error("{} file not found.", PROPERTIES_FILENAME);
            log.debug("IOException", ex);
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("There was an error in the KieContainerProducer");
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried keeping track of the current KieScanner and calling `shutdown()` on it when you re-create the new KieContainer?

Comment: Haven't tried that, but was thinking about that solution too. It feels however as a workaround, as you are still constantly starting and stopping the Scanner. In my opinion a singleton scanner should just be running in the background, created at startup and only recreating if for some reason the bean is destroyed

Comment: Do you want me to write an answer saying that if there is only one way to do it then this way isn't a workaround ;-) ? If you need a new scanner for each new container, then that's it. There may be a good reason for not being able to swap containers within a running scanner but I don't know. You might ask this on the Drools list.

Comment: I don't need a new scanner for each container. I do however need an injectable KieContainer that is updated from the maven repository. Maybe I am completely lost on the structure of the KieServices Factory...

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: Use scopes on producer methods. Producer methods may specify scope of the bean produced. This is clearly stated in [cdi specification](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#declaring_producer_method)

**Long answer**:

1. If the KieContainer is reusable object and it is safe for all beans to share one instance, please do consider annotating your producer method with `@ApplicationScoped`. Please do note there is a difference between `@Singleton` and @ApplicationScoped. Also please note I am talking about producer method, not the producer bean class.
2. If the KieContainer is not reusable, but the inner KieScanner is, create another producer method annotated with `@ApplicationScoped` and inject that KieScanner into the KieContainer method. It will be reused.
3. If neither of those can be reused, please consider annotating your current producer class with `@Dependent`.